# SQL Format difficulty

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a question about a SQL statement. I have the following statement:

```
SELECT id, user_id, receiver AS friend 
FROM messages 
WHERE user_id = %d || receiver = %d
```

In the same table (messages) are two more fields:

1. Storage_A
2. Storage_B

Now I want to do something else with this SQL:

I only want to select the rows where `Storage_A != 0 when user_id = %d`

AND

I only want to select the rows where `Storage_B != 0 when receiver = %d`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `AND` condition to add those extra checking like below

```
SELECT id, user_id, receiver AS friend 
FROM messages 
WHERE (Storage_A != 0 and user_id = %d)
AND (Storage_B != 0 and receiver = %d)
```

Even though you said, you want both the condition to match but I think you want to do `OR` between them. So the `WHERE` condition would be

```
where (Storage_A <> 0 and user_id = 8)

OR

(Storage_B <> 0 and receiver = 9)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use parentheses to group your clauses.

```
SELECT
    id, user_id, receiver AS friend
FROM
    messages
WHERE
    (user_id = %d && Storage_A != 0)
    OR (receiver = %d && Storage_B != 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your indexes are set up, you might have to do two queries and `UNION` them

```
SELECT id, user_id, receiver AS friend 
  FROM messages 
  WHERE Storage_A != 0 AND user_id = %d
UNION
SELECT id, user_id, receiver AS friend 
  FROM messages 
  WHERE Storage_B != 0 AND receiver = %d
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this too

```
  SELECT id, user_id, receiver AS friend FROM messages WHERE (Storage_A != 0 and user_id = %d) and (Storage_B != 0 and receiver = %d)
```